# Firestore database holding onto data but not updating it to the database

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Recently I have encountered a strange issue with firebase, it will just hold on to the data that i update, and if i refresh my app I still get the data and am able to modify, read etc, but it looks like it is on a temp hold or sth. the firestore database is not getting updated but in the query result i see the modified value.

Why is this happening why can't i see the actual changes in firestore database ? When i log out of the app and login again then all the changes i made is not visible, it is there only until the session is active.

this is my firestore rules as i am in development phase, I have given all excess

```
1
// Allow read/write access on all documents to any user signed in to the application
2
service cloud.firestore {
3
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
4
    match /{document=**} {
5
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
6
    }
7
  }
8
}
```

Note: I created this project 30 days ago, does it account in anyway?I have never created a local copy. I just left it running last night.

Comment: It sounds like your app is only caching the data locally, and not synchronizing it to the server. This typically means that there is either a network problem or a configuration problem. [Enable logging](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/FirebaseFirestore/setLoggingEnabled.html) and check debug output of your app for relevant messages.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like your working on a local copy of the data. Remove the [persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) of the data. As per the persistence documentation:

> For Android and Apple platforms, offline persistence is enabled by default.

Comment: nope! I have never done it,

Comment: In some cases persistence is automatically switched on and you have to force it off

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).